# Biblatex: How can I get the label [BvB60] instead of [BB60] for an article by "Bach and van Beethoven (1760)"?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I'm using the `alphabetic` style of `biblatex` as follows:

```
\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic,
  maxcitenames=3,
  minnames=3,
  useprefix=true
]{biblatex}
```

In the `.bib`-file, I have an entry:

```
@article{opera,
  author = {Bach, Johann Sebastian and van Beethoven, Ludwig},
  year = {1760},
}
```

When cited, this article will be rendered as [BB60]. Since I set `useprefix=true`, I expected the von-part to be present: [BvB60]. Is this a bug? How do I get the desired behavior without explicitly setting the label=BvB field in the BibTeX entry? And why is `false` the default value for `useprefix`?

Comment: With an up-to-date (v1.7) `biblatex` and `useprefix=true`, I get "BvB60".

Comment: @lockstep: That's strange. I'm also using biblatex 2011/11/13 v1.7

Comment: @Holger Sorry for not mentioning that you also need biber as backend.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `useprefix=true` *and biber as backend*, you get "BvB60" as label. (`backend=bibtex8` will produce "BB60".)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic,
  useprefix=true,
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{opera,
  author = {Bach, Johann Sebastian and van Beethoven, Ludwig},
  year = {1760},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With biber 1.0 and biblatex 2.0, you can also completely customise how the label is generated.

Comment: This works for me, too. The issue is that my coauthors aren't using biber. Thanks anyway!